# compilation slow down after downgrading go compiler

Tags: go

I recently got upgraded from Go 1.8.4 to 1.9 without knowing it. Compilation speed wasn't affect (not noticed at least). But I had problem with tools like `guru`, so I uninstalled 1.9 and re-installed 1.8.4. Afterwards, `go run foo.go` becomes pretty slow. I'm suspecting that the older version of the compiler cannot use cache from 1.9 and had to recompile everything from scratch - I have no prove.

Is my suspicion correct? If so, is there a way I can reset the compiler cache?

Comment: "older version of the compiler cannot use cache from 1.9 and had to recompile everything from scratch" Yes.

Comment: thanks, how can i clean the cache so?

Comment: There is no need to clear the cache. Quite the contrary. You should _populate_ your cache with the packages built via 1.8.4 if you want to speed up your builds. But deleting pkg is fine and a good way to start afresh.

Comment: `guru` (and all the common tooling) works fine with go1.9+. Update those packages rather than revert Go to an old version.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder `$GOPATH\pkg`. That is the package cache folder.

If you run the compiler with the `-v` flag it will list all the packages being compiled. If it keeps compiling the same packages that you have not changed then you know it is not using the cache.

In the past I have found that when compiling code with `run`/`build` the compiler does not cache packages, but it does cache them when using `install`.